# Не отправляется письмо через smtp mail - время ожидания операции истекло

Tags: c#, .net, веб-программирование, smtp

Написал маленькую прогу на WinForms с опцией отправки сообщения. Собсно код :

```
   SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru", 465);
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("vasiliy.aksenov.97@mail.ru", "11aa11aa");
            client.EnableSsl = true;  
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress("vasiliy.aksenov.97@mail.ru");
            mail.To.Add("vasiliy.aksenov.97@mail.ru");
            mail.Subject = "Получен новый заказ на " + OrderData.clothingTypeRuss;
            mail.Body = "test";
        try
        {
            client.Send(mail);
            MessageBox.Show("Заказ успешно отправлен ", "Отправка");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Source);
        }
```

не отправляет, пишет что время ожидания превышено. и тоже самое с smtp от gmail.
Может что то в коде не правильно? Хотя по отладке видно что тормозит именно на 
   client.Send(mail); Подскажите как решить проблему?

Comment: а что у вас прилетает от OrderData.clothingTypeRuss? Может это нужно преобразовать к типу, который smtp может принять?  UPD^^ subject принимает string.

Comment: прилетает строка. но проблема оказалась в другом совсем. поменял 465 на 2525 и заработало

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отлично, вы верно решили проблему. Сейчас давайте определимся с **причинами** такого поведения.

Существует два способа соединения по протоколу [SMTP](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821) c использованием SSL:

- Explicit SSL
- Implicit SSL

Explicit SSL использует порты  **25** (или **587**), или же, возможно, порт **2525** (не стандартный)

Explicit SSL означает, что клиент сначала подключается по незащищенному каналу, посылает команду `EHLO`, и если сервер сообщает о том, что шифрование поддерживается, то для включения шифрования клиент посылает команду `STARTTLS`, затем все дальнейшие коммуникации (включая аутентификацию) между клиентом и сервером уже защищены.

Implicit SSL использует порт **465** и отличается тем, что соединение *сразу* устанавливается по TLS/SSL.

В настоящее время класс [SmtpClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient?view=netframework-4.7) поддерживает только Explicit SSL, потому что Implicit SSL до сих пор не стандартизирован.

Comment: deprecated - судя по всему, кто-то [из моно](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/fa081c5ecd3b21353809d01ac2b08f7281f49ab0) затянул описание класса в доки MS, чтобы попиарить свой проект. Вот [сам класс](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/SmtpClient.cs,ebaa2d61cfed8051), никакого Obsolete там нет

Comment: вы хотите сказать что если я использую 25 порт то все равно могу отправлять защифрованные сообщения?

Comment: client.ClientCertificates.Add(new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate());
                client.EnableSsl = true; Пример такого кода отправляет сообщения защифрованно ?

Comment: @PashaPash да, пожалуй вы правы. Исправил ответ.

Comment: @Nikita запостил баг в docs, может быть исправят - они, судя по всему, мержат отписания сразу из нескольких источников.

Comment: @Сергей, если сервер поддерживает такую возможность, то да, сообщения будут отправляться по защищенному соединению. При этом если установить `EnableSSL` в true и сервер не отправит соответствующий заголовок, то сгенерируется исключение.

Answer (score 1):

Вот Вам отличный вариант отправки сообщения на почту:

[Стандартные, используемые порты](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP)

Некоторые интернет-провайдеры в целях предотвращения рассылки СПАМ закрывают для доступа 25-й порт, который требуется для работы SMTP-протокола.
Если закрыт 25-й порт.
Если почта у вас не отправляется, вероятно ваш Интернет-провайдер заблокировал 25-й порт, используемый для работы протокола SMTP.

Это ограничение можно обойти, используя порт 587 (без шифрования или с использованием TLS-шифрования) или 465 (с использованием SSL-шифрования) обычно не блокируется.

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class SettingMessage
{
    public static void MessageSend() // можете добавить аргументы
    {
       MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
       SmtpClient client = 
       new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru", Convert.ToInt32(0x19)) // сервер,порт
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Ваш Email", "Ваш пароль"),
            EnableSsl = true // обязательно!
        };
        message.From = new MailAddress("От кого посылать");
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress("Кому посылать"));
        message.Subject = "Заголовок";
        message.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        message.Body = "Текст в форме сообщения";
        message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8; // кодировка 
        string fileName = @"C:\Resume.txt"; // какой-нибудь файл
        Attachment item = new Attachment(fileName); 
        message.Attachments.Add(item);// добавляем файл к сообщению
        client.Send(message); // отправка сообщения
        MessageBox.Show("Сообщение отправлено успешно)))");
    }
}
```

Comment: можете немного пояснить почему порт = 0x19 ?

Comment: @Сергей,Используйте рекомендуемые порты в зависимости от Вашей почты

Comment: Поправил код, добавил немного полезной информации.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в порте.

```
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru", 2525);
```

так работает